# Enlarge first page text area when using different footer for first/following pages in KOMA script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, geometry

I want to configure a **different footer for the first page of a letter** than for the following pages.

I am using the `geometry`-package to define the text area and the position of the footer for the following pages while adjusting the position of the first footer using `\setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}`.

Unfortunately the text area of the first page gets cropped:
[image: cropped]

While I want the following behavior which I managed to force with `\enlargethispage{\dimexpr 20mm-\topskip \relax}` right after `\begin{letter}`:

[image: wanted]

I managed to achieve this in a `.cls` style class using

```
\AtBeginLetter{\enlargethispage{\dimexpr 27.4mm-\topskip \relax}}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do so? Why does `enlargefirstpage` does not have an effect?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[footskip=20mm]{geometry}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% do not remove this line end comment to prevent unintended indent
    Footer
}

\KOMAoptions{
    enlargefirstpage % <- no effect
}

\setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Test}
%\enlargethispage{\dimexpr 20mm-\topskip \relax} % <- wanted result
\opening{Hello}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `\KOMAoptions{enlargefirstpage}` should have an effect, you have to add option `firstfoot=false`. See the documentation for more information.

If you use `firstfoot=false` (without option `enlargefirstpage`!) you get the desired result for the text body on the first page. For the footer you can load package `scrlayer`, define a layer and a page style which can be used on the first letter page to add the footer.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[footskip=20mm]{geometry}

\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=off}% disables the default letter footer on the firs page
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  align=tl,
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  height=\dimexpr\paperheight-\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  foreground,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putUL{\raisebox{-\height}{\parbox{\layerwidth}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}}}
]{firstfoot}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firstfoot}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}{}{}% by default the first letter page uses page style empty

\setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% do not remove this line end comment to prevent unintended indent
    Footer
}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{Header}% still works as expected

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Test}
\opening{Hello}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]